# Upload via scp gives "Permisssion denied" on Karaf ssh console

Tags: ssh, upload, scp, karaf

The scp command to get a file from the Karaf directories via Karaf ssh console works well : 
`scp -P 8101 karaf@localhost:/deploy/README`
(after I have entered the password)

But the reverse operation to upload a file fails with a "Permission denied" error : 
`scp README -v -P 8101 karaf@localhost:/deploy/`

I tried to locally remove the file first, same error. I gave 777 on the "deploy" directory, and also tried with a new test directory.

Where can it come from ? 
Thanks
Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

Found it : the -P option cannot be anywhere in the line, it has to be before the local and remote filenames